# Visually merge lines without merging the attributes of each segment using QGIS

Tags: qgis, linestring

I am tracing the existing cycle network in my city. Some cycle paths are continuous but present different features, which correspond to different attributes per segment. I would like these lines to be visually joint but with different attributes per segment.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the two selected line elements represent a continuous cycle path, but with different attributes (for example: TIP_SEP_DX). If you look at the map, the lines are physycally separated. I would like their vertices to coincide though maintaining the sepcific attributes of each segment.

I am using QGIS.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning it. I am editing the title.

Comment: If you are digitizing these turn on snapping to vertex for the layer and manually connect them.  If you are fixing a lot of already digitized lines that don't meet, then you could try the snap geometries to layer tool or v.grass clean.  You may need to try different tolerances, you want to be large enough to fix most of the gaps without causing problems elsewhere.  You may need to do some manual fixes afterward.  The topology checker plugin can identify all dangles in a line layer.